# How to properly save updates to domain objects in Groovy/Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, persistence, grails-orm

I'm starting to touch the Groovy/Grails backend of my organization and am tasked with updating the `User` on our `Document` domain object. The problem is, after hitting the update endpoint from the frontend with the correct params attached, the backend responds with an unchanged `Document` object.

Here is the code:

```
 if (requestParams.userEmail) {
    def contact = User.findByEmail(requestParams.userEmail)
    log.debug('Reading user found by passed email contact={} error={}',contact, contact.errors.allErrors.inspect())

    if (!contact) {
       response.status = 400
       render WebserviceError.badInput as JSON
       return
    }

    document.user = contact
    document.user.save(flush: true)
 }
 document.save(flush: true)
 render survey as JSON
```

The frontend returns a promise and I'm logging the promise response, and it shows an unchanged Document object with the same exact user attached. I don't receive a 400 so it looks like the contact is successfully found.

I tried adding `flush:true` to the `user.save` call and the `document.save` call and that did not help.

Are there any obvious wrongdoings in my code?

Comment: Not seeing you make any changes to the `contact` object... why save it (even if by a different reference)?  Also, you're rendering a `survey`, not a `document`.

Answer (score 0):

Well db operations should be in a service, not in a controller, using @Transactional, preferably the gorm version not the spring version. You shouldn't need to use flush: true. Then fron the service you can return to the controller, andrender as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t state that you see the debug statement on the server indicating a found user, perhaps it’s never actually getting to this section?

I assume that the code provided is incomplete, as we don’t see that the `survey` being returned contains the `document` that’s being updated. And also the braces look unbalanced, as if there’s a control flow issue. (i.e. why are there 2 opening braces but 3 closing braces?)

I’d suggest that you use a debugger on your code to see how control is actually flowing. Most Java IDEs support easy debugging, essentially clicking the debug button rather than the run button. Set a number of breakpoints sprinkled through this code to catch requests and call the API endpoint from your frontend.

Answer (score 0):

is Document the parent? User a child?

User.addTodocument(someUser)

then Document.merge()